# How do you sort an array by two fields (date included)

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array of objects that I want to sort first by date and next by its numeric value.

```
let arr = [  
  {date: 2018-06-19 12:05:43.232Z, value: 3},
  {date: 2018-06-20 12:05:43.232Z, value: 4},  
  {date: 2018-06-18 12:05:43.232Z, value: 2},  
  {date: 2018-06-20 12:05:43.232Z, value: 4}, 
  {date: 2018-06-19 12:05:43.232Z, value: 5},     
  {date: 2018-06-18 12:05:43.232Z, value: 5},  
  {date: 2018-06-20 12:05:43.232Z, value: 5},  
  {date: 2018-06-19 12:05:43.232Z, value: 4},  
]
```

I want to sort each index by the date and the value so the result would be :

```
let arr = [
  {date: 2018-06-18 12:05:43.232Z, value: 2},
  {date: 2018-06-18 12:05:43.232Z, value: 5},

  {date: 2018-06-19 12:05:43.232Z, value: 3},
  {date: 2018-06-19 12:05:43.232Z, value: 4},
  {date: 2018-06-19 12:05:43.232Z, value: 5}, 

  {date: 2018-06-20 12:05:43.232Z, value: 3},
  {date: 2018-06-20 12:05:43.232Z, value: 4},     
  {date: 2018-06-20 12:05:43.232Z, value: 5},     
]
```

How can it be done?

Comment: By googling `js array sort`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects

Comment: not the same issue. I am looking to sort by two fields. Thats my problem. I can sort by date or by value but  am looking to sort by both

Comment: In a callback you can compare over 9000 fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Array.sort with `||`

```js
const res = arr.sort((a, b) => Date.parse(a.date) - Date.parse(b.date) || a.value - b.value);
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script>
let arr = [{
    date: '2018-06-19 12:05:43.232Z',
    value: 3
  },
  {
    date: '2018-06-20 12:05:43.232Z',
    value: 4
  },
  {
    date: '2018-06-18 12:05:43.232Z',
    value: 2
  },
  {
    date: '2018-06-20 12:05:43.232Z',
    value: 4
  },
  {
    date: '2018-06-19 12:05:43.232Z',
    value: 5
  },
  {
    date: '2018-06-18 12:05:43.232Z',
    value: 5
  },
  {
    date: '2018-06-20 12:05:43.232Z',
    value: 5
  },
  {
    date: '2018-06-19 12:05:43.232Z',
    value: 4
  },
]
</script>
```

Comment: thank you so much work perfectly!

Comment: You're welcome @obiwankenoobi

Answer (score 0):

Yo can do it using lodash library. If you check the docs of [orderBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#orderBy) function you'll see that, it is exactly what you need.

```
let arr = [  
  {"date": "2018-06-19 12:05:43.232Z", "value": 3},
  {"date": "2018-06-20 12:05:43.232Z", "value": 4},  
  {"date": "2018-06-18 12:05:43.232Z", "value": 2},  
  {"date": "2018-06-20 12:05:43.232Z", "value": 4}, 
  {"date": "2018-06-19 12:05:43.232Z", "value": 5},     
  {"date": "2018-06-18 12:05:43.232Z", "value": 5},  
  {"date": "2018-06-20 12:05:43.232Z", "value": 5},  
  {"date": "2018-06-19 12:05:43.232Z", "value": 4}  
]
```

Applying `_orderBy` on your array as follows:

```
_.orderBy(arr, ['date', 'value'], ['asc', 'asc']);
```

will get you the result that you want.

Check the example below:

```js
let arr = [  
  {"date": "2018-06-19 12:05:43.232Z", "value": 3},
  {"date": "2018-06-20 12:05:43.232Z", "value": 4},  
  {"date": "2018-06-18 12:05:43.232Z", "value": 2},  
  {"date": "2018-06-20 12:05:43.232Z", "value": 4}, 
  {"date": "2018-06-19 12:05:43.232Z", "value": 5},     
  {"date": "2018-06-18 12:05:43.232Z", "value": 5},  
  {"date": "2018-06-20 12:05:43.232Z", "value": 5},  
  {"date": "2018-06-19 12:05:43.232Z", "value": 4}  
]



console.log(_.orderBy(arr, ['date', 'value'], ['asc', 'asc']))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```